# How to replace a comment line which start with specific characters

Tags: perl, sed

I have a fortran code with global comments, which start with a double exclamation mark (i.e., !!) and personal comments, which start with a single exclamation mark (i.e., !), and I just want to hide my personal comment lines (or substitute the line with another line, e.g., '! jw'). For example, the original code looks like this:

```
!! This is a global comment  
Code..
Code..

! This is a personal comment 
code... ! This is a personal comment

!! This is a global comment
code...
```

Then, I want to update the original code as:

```
!! This is a global comment  
Code..
Code..

! jw
code... ! jw

!! This is a global comment
code...
```

I have tried to use "sed" and "awk", but I failed. So, would someone can help me? I prefer to use "sed" instead "awk" by the way.

Comment: In Fortran, a comment line starts with "!". No matter where "!" starts, after "!" is treated as a comment line. That is why I can use both "!!" or "!" or even "! " for a comment line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ```
   sed '/!!/!s/!.*/! jw/' file
  ```

  - `/!!/!` If the line does not contain `!!`, then
  - `s/!.*/! jw/` substitute all following a exclamation mark with `! jw`.
- ```
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="!"}$2{$2=" jw"}1' file
  ```

  - `BEGIN{FS=OFS="!"}` Set the field separators to `!`.
  - `$2{$2=" jw"}` If the 2nd field is not empty, substitute it by  `jw`.
  - `1` Print the line.

Answer (score 2):

Use Perl one-liner with negative lookbehind pattern:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!!)!\s.*/! jw/' in_file > out_file
```

To change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(?<!!)!\s.*/! jw/' in_file
```

To change multiple files in-place, for example `ex*.f90` files:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(?<!!)!\s.*/! jw/' ex*.f90
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`(?<!!)!` : Exclamation point that is not preceded by an exclamation point.
`\s` : Whitespace.
`.*` : Any character, repeated 0 or more times.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlre`: Negative lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?%3C!pattern))
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: Thank you, Timur. When I execute the code I have the following error:                         
String found where operator expected at ./main.prl line 3, near "pe 's/(?<!!)!\s.*/! jw/'"
        (Do you need to predeclare pe?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./main.prl line 3, near "'s/(?<!!)!\s.*/! jw/' main"
        (Missing operator before main?)
syntax error at ./main.prl line 3, near "perl -"
Execution of ./main.prl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Jungwoo This is a Perl one liner, meaning that the code should be executed in the shell, that is, on the command line in UNIX/Linux/macOS. You should execute it in the same way as you execute `sed 's/^! /! jw/' in_file > out_file` in the other answer.

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you so much. I have one more question. I have more than 50 fortran source codes, and I want to do this step for all source codes. Then, is there any possibility I can do this job at once? For example, if I have 'ex1.f90' ~ 'ex50.f90', and I want change them all.

Answer (score -1):

If the line starts with ! then you could do something like

```
sed 's/^! /! jw/' mycode.fortran >newcodefile.fortran
```

I would put it into a new file then rename after.  If you overwrite your file you could end up cause problems if anything goes wrong.

The s in the string to sed tells it to search, and replace.
the ^ means start of line, so if the comment is further in the line than the beginning this won't find that comment.
Then we search for a line that starts with ! followed by a space and replace with ! jw
If you just run it as:

```
sed 's/^! /! jw/' mycode.fortran
```

without redirecting the output to a file it will stream the output to your console so you can see if it's working.  Then run it again output to a file with the redirect >, check the file then do your renaming.  Don't get rid of your original code file until your completely sure it worked and didn't do anything you didn't want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this approach doesn't work. It changes '! ' to '! jw' only if the sentence (code) starts with '! '. For example. it changes '! This is a personal comment' to '! jwThis is a personal comment'.